# MySql group and filter results : error

Tags: mysql, group-by

I need help :
this query works perfectly well

```
select count(distinct(a.mat)),count(distinct(c.mail)) as nb 
from aca as a 
left join c on c.mat=a.mat 
group by a.mat
order by nb desc;
```

but when I want to filter

```
select count(distinct(a.mat)),count(distinct(c.mail)) as nb 
from aca as a 
left join c on c.mat=a.mat 
group by a.mat
order by nb desc
where nb > 0;
```

I get this error

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where nb>0' at line 6

What's wrong in my query ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditions on grouped function should be put into HAVING clause:

```
select count(distinct(a.mat)),count(distinct(c.mail)) as nb 
from aca as a 
left join c on c.mat=a.mat 
group by a.mat
having nb > 0
order by nb desc;
```

Answer (score 4):

Order by should always be last

```
select count(distinct(a.mat)),count(distinct(c.mail)) as nb 
from aca as a 
left join c on c.mat=a.mat 
group by a.mat
having nb > 0
order by nb desc
```

Comment: Forgot that its aggregate! Edited